# Передача данных между страницами Page

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Доброго времени суток, Господа.
У меня есть приложение, которое имеет одно окно, в нем определен Frame контрол, и несколько страниц. Все страницы наследуются от этого класса:

```
public class BasePage<VM> : Page where VM : BasePageViewModel, new()
{
    private VM viewModel;
    public VM ViewModel
    {
        get {  return viewModel; }
        set
        {
            if( viewModel == value )
                return;

            viewModel = value;
            this.DataContext = viewModel;
        }
    }

    public BasePage( IPageNavigator pageNavigator )
    {
        ViewModel = new VM();
        ViewModel.PageNavigator = pageNavigator;
    }
}
```

Объект, представляющий экземпляр наследника IPageNavigator, выглядит таким образом:

```
public class PageNavigator : BaseViewModel, IPageNavigator
{

    private Dictionary<Type, Page> pages = new Dictionary<Type, Page>();

    public Page CurrentPage { get; set; }

    public void NextPage<T>()
    {
        Type key = typeof( T );

        if( pages.TryGetValue( key, out var value ) )
        {
            CurrentPage = value;
            return;
        }

        Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance( typeof( T ), this );
        pages.Add( key, page );
        CurrentPage = page;
    }
}
```

он создается в `MainWindowViewModel` - ViewModel главного окна и сразу же устанавливается стартовая страница:

```
PageNavigator = new PageNavigator();
PageNavigator.NextPage<MainPage>();
```

свойство `public Page CurrentPage { get; set; }` соответственно привязано к Frame.

Теперь вопрос: Как передавать данные между страницами? К примеру в `MainPage` у меня в ListBox отображен некий список, по нажатию на пункт списка, должен произойти переход на другую страницу `CalculatorPricePage` с передачей пункта в виде параметра. Я сделал команду в `MainPage`, при срабатывании которой, происходит такой обработчик:

```
private void OnCalculatorPriceProductRequest( Product product )
{
    // Как передать product в CalculatorPriceProductPage???

    // Осуществляем переход
    PageNavigator.NextPage<CalculatorPriceProductPage>();
}
```

Не подскажете как это можно правильно реализовать в рамках MVVM?

Comment: Самый простой способ: устанавливать модель в качестве DataContext страницы.

Comment: @John у меня в DataContext суется VM этой страницы

Comment: Почему у вас один VM на обе страницы? По хорошему у вас для `MainPage` должна быть `MainVM` содержащая список `CalculatorPriceVM`. При выборе из списка элемента, вы уже его передаёте `CalculatorPricePage` в `DataContext`.

Comment: У меня не один VM на обе страницы. С чего Вы взяли? У меня для каждой странице свой VM. Страницы `MainPage ` и `CalculatorPricePage` никак не связаны, кроме как передачей данных, поэтому хранить в `MainPageVM` список `CalculatorPriceVM` не вижу смысла. Мне нужно просто передать данных от одной страницы, в другую

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите, что неправильно. В рамках MVVM страница не должна создавать себе VM. Это не её сфера компетенции: она не знает, как правильно создать VM и как связать её с другими VM. Именно поэтому у вас в VM нужен пустой конструктор. Таким образом, у вас VM создаются в отрыве друг от друга, и не могут друг с другом коммуницировать без каких-нибудь костылей. Это неправильно.

Правильный подход такой. Вы создаёте нужные VM-объекты, раздаёте им нужные ссылки друг на друга. Когда у вас создаётся View, оно получает свою VM со стороны, и таким образом не должно создавать её (как мы выяснили, оно и не может это сделать толково).

Теперь, если различные VM имеют ссылки на другие VM, где надо, то обмен информацией между ними тривиален. (Публичный метод, публичные свойства, подписка на события, да что угодно.) А View будет просто подхватывать состояние VM, как оно и должно.